# Basic Eloquent Relationship Enquiry - One to One

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
**USER MODEL**
public function post(){
return $this->hasOne('App\Post','user_id','id');
}

**WEB ROUTE**
use App\User;

Route::get('/{id}/post',function($id){
return User::find($id)->post;
});
```

Hi everyone, I'm fairly new to both PHP and Laravel and have been struggling a bit. I just have 2 questions for this code.

In the web routes, why doesn't post have any () beside it? It was declared a function in the user model. And.. I am unsure of how these relationships work (correct me if I am wrong) but does the code above look for a user with a specific $id and connects it with a post having a similar $user_id value?

Comment: In the model the method defines the relationship and provides it as an object. And yes, the user record matching that id will be returned. The docs are your friend https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

For the first bit, it is a dynamic property, here you can find how you can actually make one yourself [Laravel: create a dynamic property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125724/laravel-create-a-dynamic-property). They essentially work because the result is a single object search based on the id, since it doesn't have to retrieve a collection it allows itself to be accessed like an attribute of the object.

And yea pretty much on the second one. It also uses laravels models to retrieve the data from the database so that you get an object back without needing to create the repositories yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are major differences between `User::find($id)->post` and `User::find($id)->post()`. First one is returning the result of the related relations so you get the **post** that has **user_id** equal to **$id**.
The second one returns a query builder,so you can add more conditions. For example `User::find($id)->post()->where("status", 1)->get()`.